# Why maven doesn't generate project reports?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

It's Maven 3.0. I'm creating a new project:

```
mvn archetype:create
```

Then I'm creating a file `site/site.xml`:

```
<project name="foo">
  <body>
    <menu name="Overview">
      <item name="Introduction" href="index.html" />
    </menu>
    <menu ref="reports" />
  </body>
</project>
```

Then I'm adding a reporting plugin to `pom.xml`:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Then I run `mvn site` and it says `"BUILD SUCCESS"`. But I don't see any reports in project site (reporting menu item is not there). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maven 3 reporting [is different](http://www.wakaleo.com/blog/292-site-generation-in-maven-3).

```
[...]
<build>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-beta-2</version>
    <configuration>
      <reportPlugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <reports>
            <report>cim</report>
            <report>issue-tracking</report>
          </reports>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </reportPlugins>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</build>
[...]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. I'll add that if you want the report to generate the index.html file, you have to also put the 'index' report under the reports section.

Comment: The link you provided no longer works.  Do you have any other sources?  EDIT: I found the link: http://www.wakaleo.com/blog/site-generation-in-maven-3

Comment: @Scot The documentation says the `reportPlugins` element is marked private and should not be used (yet?):
[maven 3 info on maven-site-plugin site](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html#New_Configuration_Maven_3_only_no_reports_configuration_inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

This pom works (even if you don't define site.xml file)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>it.cucchiara</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have Maven 3.0, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: If you are using Maven 3.0, I think you need to use a newer site plugin.

Answer (score -1):

yes maven 3 reporting is different. Hint: For maven 3 you could like to use the maven-site-plugin in version 3.0-beta-2 (site plugin version 3.0-beta-3 run's in an error on my computer with maven 3.0-beta-3). This will be work fine. But for the reports: change report or changelog i must be use the old manner of reporting additional.

Here the interesting parts of my pom.xml.

```
        <build>
        :
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0-beta-2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>createsite</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <reportPlugins>
                    <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                        <reportSets>
                        <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                          <report>dependencies</report>
                          <report>license</report>
                          <report>scm</report>
                          <report>project-team</report>
                        </reports>
                        </reportSet>
                        </reportSets>
                    </plugin>
                </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
      :
    <build>

    <reporting>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
        <reports>
          <report>changes-report</report>
        </reports>
        </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Comment: Hello Vincenzo, thanks for your correction. I had your problem too and so i have tried many variants. Maybe my variant describe here has worked only at radom.
Should i remove my answer?