# maven-site plugins 3.3 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DocumentContent

Tags: java, maven

Since this night, maven site 3.3 plugins stop to work.

Try to delete local repository, but no change.
Maven 3.3.9
java 1.8

No config or dependencies defined in pom for site plugins

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.CiManagementReport
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/DocumentContent
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why maven doesn't generate project reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112346/why-maven-doesnt-generate-project-reports)

Answer (score 188, accepted):

I had just started to get this issue also during builds. What worked for me was to specifically define the `maven-site-plugin` and the `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` along with the version numbers in the pom.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.7.1</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, i just add the maven-project-info-reports-plugin with version 2.7 in pom and it's ok now.

Comment: For the record: should be added to build/plugins .

Answer (score 99):

This is caused by `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` updated to 3.0.0, and rely on `doxia-site-renderer` 1.8 (and have `org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DocumentContent` this class), but `maven-site-plugin:3.3` rely on `doxia-site-renderer:1.4` (and do not have `org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DocumentContent`)

We can specific `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` version in `reporting` part:

```
        <reporting>
            <plugins>           
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                </plugin>           
            </plugins>    
        </reporting>
```

Or we can specify `maven-site-plugin` to the latest 3.7.1 like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
</plugin>
```

in `build` part of pom.

Comment: This is actually the real cause. I was wondering what (or better who) triggered this to update? Where does maven get this information from?

Comment: @mbreck yes, we need to add config to every pom.

Comment: the maven-site-plugin version needs to be specified in the projects plugin section to work. The "new" reports section has confused me a lot and seems to be redundant. For me maven is close to unusable these days.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I defined `maven-checkstyle-plugin (3.0.0)` and `maven-project-info-reports-plugin (2.9)` in the `<reporting>` section of `pom.xml`

Comment: It worked for me only after downgrading maven-project-info-reports-plugin to v2.9, even though I have used maven-site-plugin v3.7.1

Comment: As already reported you need to downgrade to v2.9 even if maven-site is already at 3.7.1. Please update your answer.

Comment: @DaveMoten  I need to check again, but when I post the answers, I test two methods. and make sure, you need to add config to every pom including parent pom.

Answer (score 21):

Version of the maven site plugin needs to be explicitly set in the build section too. Here is the example:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>index</report>
                        <report>licenses</report>
                        <report>dependency-info</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Part of Maven - specified version explicitly for compatibility
             with the maven-project-info-reports-plugin 3.0.0-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you! Was getting the error while following Maven's Getting Started guide and executing "mvn site". After adding your snippet to my pom.xml, command works now.

Comment: @WallTearer that was exactly the case. I don't know if it has a different behavior following the tutorials typing in the console or in Eclipse (it shouldn't I guess). Anyway, I guess the user guide should be updated.

Comment: TheJeff is the man. I guess that it is the `<build>` vs `<reporting>` separation that made it work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Maven 3 doesn't support Doxia anymore.

Use

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Reference: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html

Answer (score 2):

You really need to add more information (I didn't downvote BTW).

IIRC; if you don't specify a version for a plugin bound to lifecycle phases, you'll get the latest.

Try:

- Upgrading to the latest version of maven - [3.5.4](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) `ATOW`
- Running `mvn help:effective-pom` and checking which versions are
  actually being resolved - if you have an old log from CI or wherever
  to compare with..
- Explicity setting the `maven-site-plugin` version
  in `pluginManagement` section
- Adding a dependency to `maven-site-plugin` (see below)

`org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/DocumentContent` can be found in `doxia-site-renderer`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
        <artifactId>doxia-site-renderer</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I suspect explicitly setting the version of maven-site-plugin to whatever you used to use (incidentally) will work.

---

**Edit:** Was chasing a similar issue in maven plugin build testing, explicitly setting `maven-site-plugin` version (3.7.1 ATOW) in integration pom used by `maven-invoker-plugin` has worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The following versions in pom.xml fixed the problem for me:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also hit this error on some of my build jobs today. The fix suggested above, adding a concrete dependency for the maven-site-plugin does work and fixes this issue.

However, what it highlighted for me was the fact I was even running the mvn site goal, which I didn't even know we were running and we don't really require.

My fix was to therefore remove the site goal from my mvn arg, as although the site it creates is actually quite useful, I never knew we were creating it, we never published it anywhere and were actually deleting it every build anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow Changhua's advice, and define maven-project-info-reports-plugin to version 3.0.0, and maven-site-plugin to 3.7.1 in my pom file, but found that the maven site still pulled in version 3.3 of the maven-site-plugin, regardless of how I set it.

I finally realized that my problem had to do with our project structure.  We have a parent pom, in which we were defining the maven-site-plugin dependency, which was then inherited by the children poms.  However, the build pom file was separate, and didn't define maven-site-plugin at all, which allowed maven to pull in the 3.3 version on its own.  I added the maven-site-plugin dependency (version 3.7.1) to the build pom file, so that it now exists in both the build pom file and the parent pom file, and now the build is correctly using version 3.7.1, and is passing again.