# Why does maven-site-plugin always use version 3.3?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-site-plugin

I am experiencing the same problem described in [maven-site plugins 3.3 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DocumentContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091539/maven-site-plugins-3-3-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-maven-doxia)

I'm trying to set the versions for maven-site-plugin (to 3.7.1) and maven-project-info-reports-plugin-version (to 3.0.0) as described in one of the answers.  I'm using Eclipse, so I look in the "Effective POM" tab for the pom file I'm working on, and can see that the versions for those plugins are 3.7.1 and 3.0.0, as I specified.

However, when I run mvn help:effective-pom, the output shows maven-site-plugin twice - one with a version of 3.7.1, as I want, and the other with a version of 3.3.  When I run mvn site, the output shows that it is using maven-site-plugin 3.3.

So my question is, where is that reference to maven-site-plugin version 3.3 coming from, and how can I force it to use 3.7.1?  I'm already specifying it in the pom file, but it still uses version 3.3.

Here's my definition for the maven-site-plugin:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
    </plugin>
```

By the way, this is a parent pom file, but it is the only reference that I have to maven-site-plugin in it or any of the child pom files.

I'm using maven version 3.2.1.

Comment: Check your dependency tree.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the maven dependency tree.  I haven't used that before, and it looks like it should tell me which dependency is pulling in the unexpected version of maven-site-plugin.  Unfortunately, I'm struggling to get the information I need from it.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to use the mvn dependency:tree option?  I'm currently using "mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -DoutputType=graphml", but the output file doesn't mention maven-site-plugin at all.

Comment: It's a complete transitive dependency tree-grep the output?

Comment: I am grepping the output, but I don't seem to be getting a complete tree.  If I were, then I should see maven-site-plugin somewhere.  I've changed my grep statement to look for another jar that does appear in the output file, and it gives me the output that I expect.  But when I change to grep for maven-site-plugin, I find nothing.  I thought I must be doing something wrong, that I'm not getting a complete tree, and was hoping for advice on what's wrong with me maven dependency:tree command.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the project structure.  We're using a parent pom file, with several dependent poms, and then a build pom.  mvn dependency:tree doesn't seem to show me the entire dependency tree, I believe because of that structure.  Defining the maven-site-plugin version to use in both the parent pom and the build pom, instead of only in the parent pom, might help me solve my underlying problem.

Comment: I have faced the same issue. I used 3.7 but it is picking 3.3. I tried to run the command mvn -e site to see in which child modules 3.3 version plugin is picked up and getting failed. Whichever module it is picking 3.3 I have added the same plugin in that child module and it worked !!!. Also, for me one of the child modules is outside the parent root directory,there also i have added the same. Hope this will resolve your issue. Good Luck !

Answer (score 10):

Maven does not always use [maven-site-plugin](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.maven.plugins%20AND%20a:maven-site-plugin) version 3.3.

In fact the plugin version being used during `site` lifecycle is specified in **Apache Maven** project itself, in [maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.1.0/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml#L130-L137):

```xml
<default-phases>
  <site>
    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site
  </site>
  <site-deploy>
    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:deploy
  </site-deploy>
</default-phases>
```

**Before maven 3.1.0**

```
version 3.2
```

**Since maven 3.1.0**

```
version 3.3
```

See this [commit](https://github.com/apache/maven/commit/4ec06bf67cc6bdffa026f46c5836e3bc895865ed) for more info.

**Since maven 4.0.0**

```
version 3.9.1
```

Following [MNG-7263](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7263), the plugin version is specified in [SiteLifecycleProvider.java](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/lifecycle/providers/SiteLifecycleProvider.java#L45-L46):

```
phases.put( "site", new LifecyclePhase( "org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.9.1:site" ) );
phases.put( "site-deploy", new LifecyclePhase( "org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.9.1:deploy" ) );
```

### Issue fix

To override the **maven-site-plugin** version add it to the `build` section of the POM file and [maven-project-info-reports-plugin](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.maven.plugins%20AND%20a:maven-project-info-reports-plugin) to `reporting`. Here is a full working example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>mavenproject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <url>http://www.your.site.com/</url>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

</project>
```

Then generate a project site:

```
$ mvn site 

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.mycompany:mavenproject >---------------------
[INFO] Building mavenproject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site (default-site) @ mavenproject ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:3.0.0
[INFO] 15 reports detected for maven-project-info-reports-plugin:3.0.0: ci-management, dependencies, dependency-info, dependency-management, distribution-management, index, issue-management, licenses, mailing-lists, modules, plugin-management, plugins, scm, summary, team
...
```

Comment: Alas this advice doesn't work with the maven-release-plugin. Bug raised here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-1052

Comment: Your advice wasn't enough, I needed to add an execution also : `<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.9.1</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>attach-descriptor</id>
             <goals>
                 <goal>attach-descriptor</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>`