# Maven - Error with building project

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I would like to give as good of description as possible but I have no really understanding of `Maven`. I was running my project, but unfortunately it is no longer working.

Here is my error:

> [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
>
> [INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:3.0.0
>
> [WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.CiManagementReport
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/DocumentContent
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)

Any help would be appreciated, I really don't know what the problem is.

Comment: The compiler didn't find the class DocumentContent. Make sure the library containing the class is included in your pom.xml. Run maven update command to make sure the library is retrieved.

Comment: Do you know the code for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maven-site plugins 3.3 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DocumentContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091539/maven-site-plugins-3-3-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-maven-doxia)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this library is added to your pom.xml. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.8.1

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
    <artifactId>doxia-site-renderer</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Afterwards, run a maven clean and install. If you are using eclipse, this can be triggered by right clicking the project and selecting 'Run As'

```
mvn clean install
```